# Need help editing Google Scripts for multiple sheets in workbook

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, data-validation

I am attempting to use this script to choose multiple selections in 1 cell for data validation in google sheets. I cannot get the script to work on the 200+ sheets within the workbook. Is there a way to edit the script to cover all of the sheets without adding the names of all 200+ tabs?
Any help you can provide is appreciated!!!

```
function onEdit(e) {
var oldValue;
var newValue;
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if(activeCell.getColumn() == 3 && activeCell.getRow() == 1 && ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=='Sheet1') {
newValue=e.value;
oldValue=e.oldValue;
if(!e.value) {
activeCell.setValue("");
}
else {
if (!e.oldValue) {
activeCell.setValue(newValue);
}
else {
if(oldValue.indexOf(newValue) <0) {
activeCell.setValue(oldValue+','+newValue);
}
else {
activeCell.setValue(oldValue);
}
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `&& ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=='Sheet1'` in the `if` statement.

This line is limiting the script to recognise chnages to just "Sheet1". If you remove this part of the condition, then it will work on ANY sheet